# How to use webp's target-size=value from PHP's ImageMagick extension?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, image-compression, webp

https://imagemagick.org/script/webp.php lists a similar option to `$im->setOption('jpeg:extent', '75kb')` (which limits output jpg files to 75kb for example) which is `target-size=value`.

> a target size (in bytes) to try and reach for the compressed output.
> The compressor makes several passes of partial encoding in order to
> get as close as possible to this target.

That's a command line option.

How can I get it to work in PHP's php-imagick extension?